# Behringer Xenyx Q802USB - not working input or output device (Ubuntu 21.10)

Tags: sound, usb, pulseaudio, alsa

the mixer Q802USB from Behringer is detected by the system, but not really "loaded".
An attached SoundblaserX G6 and the internal audio devices of my PC are working.
I wanted to use the mic attached to the mixer as i am doing it within Windows 10.

Here the output of pulseaudio when i attach the device - maybe somebody has an idea how i can fix it...:

```
I: [pulseaudio] (alsa-lib)main.c: error: failed to import hw:3 use case configuration -2
I: [pulseaudio] (alsa-lib)main.c: error: failed to import USB Audio CODEC use case configuration -2
I: [pulseaudio] alsa-ucm.c: UCM not available for card USB Audio CODEC
I: [pulseaudio] alsa-mixer.c: Loading path config: /usr/share//pulseaudio/alsa-mixer/paths/analog-input-mic.conf
I: [pulseaudio] alsa-util.c: Successfully attached to mixer 'hw:3'
I: [pulseaudio] alsa-mixer.c: Loading path config: /usr/share//pulseaudio/alsa-mixer/paths/analog-output.conf
I: [pulseaudio] module-card-restore.c: Restoring port latency offsets for card alsa_card.usb-Burr-Brown_from_TI_USB_Audio_CODEC-00.
I: [pulseaudio] card.c: alsa_card.usb-Burr-Brown_from_TI_USB_Audio_CODEC-00: active_profile: output:analog-stereo-output+input:analog-stereo-input
I: [pulseaudio] module-card-restore.c: Profile '' was previously automatically selected for card alsa_card.usb-Burr-Brown_from_TI_USB_Audio_CODEC-00.
I: [pulseaudio] card.c: Created 3 "alsa_card.usb-Burr-Brown_from_TI_USB_Audio_CODEC-00"
I: [pulseaudio] alsa-util.c: Cannot disable ALSA period wakeups
I: [pulseaudio] alsa-util.c: ALSA period wakeups were not disabled
I: [pulseaudio] alsa-sink.c: Successfully opened device front:3.
I: [pulseaudio] alsa-sink.c: Selected mapping 'Analog Stereo' (analog-stereo-output).
I: [pulseaudio] alsa-sink.c: Successfully enabled mmap() mode.
I: [pulseaudio] alsa-sink.c: Successfully enabled timer-based scheduling mode.
I: [pulseaudio] alsa-util.c: Successfully attached to mixer 'hw:3'
I: [pulseaudio] module-device-restore.c: Restoring volume for sink alsa_output.usb-Burr-Brown_from_TI_USB_Audio_CODEC-00.analog-stereo-output: front-left: 65536 / 100%,   front-right: 465 /   1%
I: [pulseaudio] module-device-restore.c: Restoring mute state for sink alsa_output.usb-Burr-Brown_from_TI_USB_Audio_CODEC-00.analog-stereo-output: unmuted
I: [pulseaudio] sink.c: Created sink 3 "alsa_output.usb-Burr-Brown_from_TI_USB_Audio_CODEC-00.analog-stereo-output" with sample spec s16le 2ch 44100Hz and channel map front-left,front-right
I: [pulseaudio] sink.c:     alsa.resolution_bits = "16"
I: [pulseaudio] sink.c:     device.api = "alsa"
I: [pulseaudio] sink.c:     device.class = "sound"
I: [pulseaudio] sink.c:     alsa.class = "generic"
I: [pulseaudio] sink.c:     alsa.subclass = "generic-mix"
I: [pulseaudio] sink.c:     alsa.name = "USB Audio"
I: [pulseaudio] sink.c:     alsa.id = "USB Audio"
I: [pulseaudio] sink.c:     alsa.subdevice = "0"
I: [pulseaudio] sink.c:     alsa.subdevice_name = "subdevice #0"
I: [pulseaudio] sink.c:     alsa.device = "0"
I: [pulseaudio] sink.c:     alsa.card = "3"
I: [pulseaudio] sink.c:     alsa.card_name = "USB Audio CODEC"
I: [pulseaudio] sink.c:     alsa.long_card_name = "Burr-Brown from TI USB Audio CODEC at usb-0000:2a:00.3-6.1, full speed"
I: [pulseaudio] sink.c:     alsa.driver_name = "snd_usb_audio"
I: [pulseaudio] sink.c:     device.bus_path = "pci-0000:2a:00.3-usb-0:6.1:1.0"
I: [pulseaudio] sink.c:     sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.2/0000:20:00.0/0000:21:08.0/0000:2a:00.3/usb3/3-6/3-6.1/3-6.1:1.0/sound/card3"
I: [pulseaudio] sink.c:     udev.id = "usb-Burr-Brown_from_TI_USB_Audio_CODEC-00"
I: [pulseaudio] sink.c:     device.bus = "usb"
I: [pulseaudio] sink.c:     device.vendor.id = "08bb"
I: [pulseaudio] sink.c:     device.vendor.name = "Texas Instruments"
I: [pulseaudio] sink.c:     device.product.id = "2902"
I: [pulseaudio] sink.c:     device.product.name = "PCM2902 Audio Codec"
I: [pulseaudio] sink.c:     device.serial = "Burr-Brown_from_TI_USB_Audio_CODEC"
I: [pulseaudio] sink.c:     device.string = "front:3"
I: [pulseaudio] sink.c:     device.buffering.buffer_size = "352800"
I: [pulseaudio] sink.c:     device.buffering.fragment_size = "176400"
I: [pulseaudio] sink.c:     device.access_mode = "mmap+timer"
I: [pulseaudio] sink.c:     device.profile.name = "analog-stereo-output"
I: [pulseaudio] sink.c:     device.profile.description = "Analog Stereo"
I: [pulseaudio] sink.c:     device.description = "PCM2902 Audio Codec Analog Stereo"
I: [pulseaudio] sink.c:     module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
I: [pulseaudio] sink.c:     device.icon_name = "audio-card-usb"
I: [pulseaudio] source.c: Created source 4 "alsa_output.usb-Burr-Brown_from_TI_USB_Audio_CODEC-00.analog-stereo-output.monitor" with sample spec s16le 2ch 44100Hz and channel map front-left,front-right
I: [pulseaudio] source.c:     device.description = "Monitor of PCM2902 Audio Codec Analog Stereo"
I: [pulseaudio] source.c:     device.class = "monitor"
I: [pulseaudio] source.c:     alsa.card = "3"
I: [pulseaudio] source.c:     alsa.card_name = "USB Audio CODEC"
I: [pulseaudio] source.c:     alsa.long_card_name = "Burr-Brown from TI USB Audio CODEC at usb-0000:2a:00.3-6.1, full speed"
I: [pulseaudio] source.c:     alsa.driver_name = "snd_usb_audio"
I: [pulseaudio] source.c:     device.bus_path = "pci-0000:2a:00.3-usb-0:6.1:1.0"
I: [pulseaudio] source.c:     sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.2/0000:20:00.0/0000:21:08.0/0000:2a:00.3/usb3/3-6/3-6.1/3-6.1:1.0/sound/card3"
I: [pulseaudio] source.c:     udev.id = "usb-Burr-Brown_from_TI_USB_Audio_CODEC-00"
I: [pulseaudio] source.c:     device.bus = "usb"
I: [pulseaudio] source.c:     device.vendor.id = "08bb"
I: [pulseaudio] source.c:     device.vendor.name = "Texas Instruments"
I: [pulseaudio] source.c:     device.product.id = "2902"
I: [pulseaudio] source.c:     device.product.name = "PCM2902 Audio Codec"
I: [pulseaudio] source.c:     device.serial = "Burr-Brown_from_TI_USB_Audio_CODEC"
I: [pulseaudio] source.c:     device.string = "3"
I: [pulseaudio] source.c:     module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
I: [pulseaudio] source.c:     device.icon_name = "audio-card-usb"
I: [pulseaudio] alsa-sink.c: Using 2.0 fragments of size 176400 bytes (1000.00ms), buffer size is 352800 bytes (2000.00ms)
I: [pulseaudio] alsa-sink.c: Time scheduling watermark is 20.00ms
I: [pulseaudio] alsa-sink.c: Successfully enabled deferred volume.
I: [pulseaudio] alsa-sink.c: Hardware volume ranges from -128.00 dB to 0.00 dB.
I: [pulseaudio] alsa-sink.c: Fixing base volume to 0.00 dB
I: [pulseaudio] alsa-sink.c: Using hardware volume control. Hardware dB scale supported.
I: [pulseaudio] alsa-sink.c: Using hardware mute control.
I: [alsa-sink-USB Audio] util.c: Successfully enabled SCHED_RR scheduling for thread, with priority 5.
I: [alsa-sink-USB Audio] alsa-sink.c: Starting playback.
I: [pulseaudio] core.c: configured_default_sink: alsa_output.usb-Creative_Technology_Ltd_Sound_BlasterX_G6_2400544F561-00.analog-stereo -> alsa_output.usb-Burr-Brown_from_TI_USB_Audio_CODEC-00.analog-stereo-output
I: [pulseaudio] core.c: default_sink: alsa_output.usb-Creative_Technology_Ltd_Sound_BlasterX_G6_2400544F561-00.analog-stereo -> alsa_output.usb-Burr-Brown_from_TI_USB_Audio_CODEC-00.analog-stereo-output
I: [pulseaudio] alsa-util.c: Cannot disable ALSA period wakeups
I: [pulseaudio] alsa-util.c: ALSA period wakeups were not disabled
I: [pulseaudio] alsa-source.c: Successfully opened device hw:3.
I: [pulseaudio] alsa-source.c: Selected mapping 'Analog Stereo' (analog-stereo-input).
I: [pulseaudio] alsa-source.c: Successfully enabled mmap() mode.
I: [pulseaudio] alsa-source.c: Successfully enabled timer-based scheduling mode.
I: [pulseaudio] source.c: Created source 5 "alsa_input.usb-Burr-Brown_from_TI_USB_Audio_CODEC-00.analog-stereo-input" with sample spec s16le 2ch 44100Hz and channel map front-left,front-right
I: [pulseaudio] source.c:     alsa.resolution_bits = "16"
I: [pulseaudio] source.c:     device.api = "alsa"
I: [pulseaudio] source.c:     device.class = "sound"
I: [pulseaudio] source.c:     alsa.class = "generic"
I: [pulseaudio] source.c:     alsa.subclass = "generic-mix"
I: [pulseaudio] source.c:     alsa.name = "USB Audio"
I: [pulseaudio] source.c:     alsa.id = "USB Audio"
I: [pulseaudio] source.c:     alsa.subdevice = "0"
I: [pulseaudio] source.c:     alsa.subdevice_name = "subdevice #0"
I: [pulseaudio] source.c:     alsa.device = "0"
I: [pulseaudio] source.c:     alsa.card = "3"
I: [pulseaudio] source.c:     alsa.card_name = "USB Audio CODEC"
I: [pulseaudio] source.c:     alsa.long_card_name = "Burr-Brown from TI USB Audio CODEC at usb-0000:2a:00.3-6.1, full speed"
I: [pulseaudio] source.c:     alsa.driver_name = "snd_usb_audio"
I: [pulseaudio] source.c:     device.bus_path = "pci-0000:2a:00.3-usb-0:6.1:1.0"
I: [pulseaudio] source.c:     sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.2/0000:20:00.0/0000:21:08.0/0000:2a:00.3/usb3/3-6/3-6.1/3-6.1:1.0/sound/card3"
I: [pulseaudio] source.c:     udev.id = "usb-Burr-Brown_from_TI_USB_Audio_CODEC-00"
I: [pulseaudio] source.c:     device.bus = "usb"
I: [pulseaudio] source.c:     device.vendor.id = "08bb"
I: [pulseaudio] source.c:     device.vendor.name = "Texas Instruments"
I: [pulseaudio] source.c:     device.product.id = "2902"
I: [pulseaudio] source.c:     device.product.name = "PCM2902 Audio Codec"
I: [pulseaudio] source.c:     device.serial = "Burr-Brown_from_TI_USB_Audio_CODEC"
I: [pulseaudio] source.c:     device.string = "hw:3"
I: [pulseaudio] source.c:     device.buffering.buffer_size = "352800"
I: [pulseaudio] source.c:     device.buffering.fragment_size = "176400"
I: [pulseaudio] source.c:     device.access_mode = "mmap+timer"
I: [pulseaudio] source.c:     device.profile.name = "analog-stereo-input"
I: [pulseaudio] source.c:     device.profile.description = "Analog Stereo"
I: [pulseaudio] source.c:     device.description = "PCM2902 Audio Codec Analog Stereo"
I: [pulseaudio] source.c:     module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
I: [pulseaudio] source.c:     device.icon_name = "audio-card-usb"
I: [pulseaudio] alsa-source.c: Using 2.0 fragments of size 176400 bytes (1000.00ms), buffer size is 352800 bytes (2000.00ms)
I: [pulseaudio] alsa-source.c: Time scheduling watermark is 20.00ms
I: [alsa-source-USB Audio] util.c: Successfully enabled SCHED_RR scheduling for thread, with priority 5.
I: [alsa-source-USB Audio] alsa-source.c: Starting capture.
I: [pulseaudio] core.c: configured_default_source: alsa_input.usb-Creative_Technology_Ltd_Sound_BlasterX_G6_2400544F561-00.analog-stereo -> alsa_input.usb-Burr-Brown_from_TI_USB_Audio_CODEC-00.analog-stereo-input
I: [pulseaudio] core.c: default_source: alsa_input.usb-Creative_Technology_Ltd_Sound_BlasterX_G6_2400544F561-00.analog-stereo -> alsa_input.usb-Burr-Brown_from_TI_USB_Audio_CODEC-00.analog-stereo-input
I: [pulseaudio] module.c: Loaded "module-alsa-card" (index: #24; argument: "device_id="3" name="usb-Burr-Brown_from_TI_USB_Audio_CODEC-00" card_name="alsa_card.usb-Burr-Brown_from_TI_USB_Audio_CODEC-00" namereg_fail=false tsched=yes fixed_latency_range=no ignore_dB=no deferred_volume=yes use_ucm=yes avoid_resampling=no card_properties="module-udev-detect.discovered=1"").
I: [pulseaudio] module-udev-detect.c: Card /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.2/0000:20:00.0/0000:21:08.0/0000:2a:00.3/usb3/3-6/3-6.1/3-6.1:1.0/sound/card3 (alsa_card.usb-Burr-Brown_from_TI_USB_Audio_CODEC-00) module loaded.
I: [pulseaudio] module-suspend-on-idle.c: Sink alsa_output.usb-Burr-Brown_from_TI_USB_Audio_CODEC-00.analog-stereo-output idle for too long, suspending ...
I: [alsa-sink-USB Audio] alsa-sink.c: Device suspended...
I: [pulseaudio] module-suspend-on-idle.c: Source alsa_input.usb-Burr-Brown_from_TI_USB_Audio_CODEC-00.analog-stereo-input idle for too long, suspending ...
I: [alsa-source-USB Audio] alsa-source.c: Device suspended...
```

The device is not shown in the audio device config.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Ubuntu 20.10 is out of support and off-topic here. Please install a supported release and if the problem persists we can try troubleshooting from there.

Comment: Ubuntu 20.10 (along with all flavors) is *End-of-Life* and thus unsupported on this site (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic), and many other Ubuntu sites, unless your question is specific to moving to a supported release of Ubuntu. https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/07/25/ubuntu-20-10-groovy-gorilla-end-of-life-reached-on-july-22-2021/ https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades

Comment: My bad - it is 21.10 not 20.10 .....

Comment: after research i found out that after executing "pactl load-module module-detect" the devices are listed and are working. Now i am looking why it is not loaded correctly on startup...